# Automatic tagging in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, tags

So I have this simple django Model called Post with some date about the user who posted a message and a message it self.

```
class Post(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
     related_name="posts",null=False)
     text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
     date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now = False)
     date_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
     tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name="posts")
```

And I need to implement a tagging system like twitter has it. So when Post gets saved I need to capture the tags from the text field and place them somehow in a many2many relation so that I am able to do stuff like 'tag.posts' to get all the Posts with this tag or the other way around. I have the algorithm to capture the tags but I am stuck on implementing this automatic way of creating a Tag Object when creating/editing/saving a Post. I already tried to override the save Method, create a Manager or listen to the post_save signal but it didn't work.

How is this implemented the best? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to capture **pre_save** signal and create the tags which does not exist.

Comment: How would i implement the many2many link between the classes. I read that many2many fields cannot be created at that point because the model it self is not created yet.

Comment: That you will have to do the save of the form after creating the Post.

Comment: Doing it that way would force me to create a custom Admin Form for editing / creating, is that right?